# Vscode snippet variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, template-variables

```
"snippet with class binding":{
    "prefix": "row.${variable}",
    "body":[
        "<table class=\"row ${same_variable_here}\">",
        "\t<tr>",
        "\t\t<td>",
        "\t\t\t$0",
        "\t\t</td>",
        "\t</tr>",
        "</table>"
    ]
}
```

Is it possible(and how if so) to create variables like *some_entity.classname*
expanding into something like this(in html for example):

```
<div class="classname"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two questions there.  Yes, emmet expansion will automatically turn
`div.myClass` into `<div class="myClass"></div>`.  See [emmet in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet).

Your other question is about a emmet snippet for a full table expansion. See [custom emmet snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets).  In your settings.json you will need:

```
  "emmet.extensionsPath": "C:\\Users\\Mark\\.vscode\\extensions"
```

That should point to a folder that contains a new file that you will create called `snippets.json`.  In that file put:

```
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
        "tableR": 
          "table.row.$1>tr>td"
    }
  }
}
```

Use whatever prefix you want besides "`tableR`".  Then you **must reload** vscode.  Then type your prefix and tab to expand (assuming you have the emmet tab expansion setting in your settings.]

[EDIT]: Based on your comment below, perhaps you are looking for something as simple as a snippet with a keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+n",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)\\.(.*)/<$1 class=\"$2\"><\\/$1>/}"
    }
},
```

So if you **select** `anyTag.someClass` becomes `<anyTag class="someClass"></anyTag>`
when you use whatever keybinding you have chosen.  Emmet is not involved here, this is just a simple keybinding in your keybindings.json (you can limit it to certain languages if you wish).  Emmet expansion does not allow you to transform its prefix (the regexp above) the way a plain snippet can grab the selection or current word and transform it.

Comment: _emmet expansion will automatically turn div.myClass into <div class="myClass"></div>. See emmet in vscode._  << Mostly my question is about this part, but implemented on a snippet: to turn 'snippet_name.var' **in a structure with autofilled var**(fill class _not_ by using tabstop, _but_ from emmet phrase)

Comment: Please edit your question. "In a structure with autofilled var" I could guess at what you mean by that but you should make it explicit in your question with a good example.

Comment: So, i think edited section of your answer is almost satisfying my question. Still bad that snippets themselves isn't emmet-like.