# vscode emmet, how to expand div. to <div styleName=''"></div> other than <div className=""></div>

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I am working in *react* with *react-css-module*. In jsx, emment provides `className` for `.`'s expansion. but now I want to expand:

`anytagName.` (or `anytagName,`)

to

```
<anyTagName styleName=''></anyTagName>
```

To make double quotes to single quotes, I read some doc and solve this problem.

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "attr_quotes": "single"
    },
    "jsx": {
        "attr_quotes": "single",
        "self_closing_tag": true
    }
}
```

How can I expand something to the `styleName` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my edited answer [Vscode snippet variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856237/vscode-snippet-variable/51861028#51861028)

You could do this with a simple keybinding or an emmet expansion.  Here is the keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+n",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "<${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} styleName='$1'>$0<\/${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}>"
    }
}
```

Choose whatever keybinding you wish.  Select your `anyTag`, hit the keybinding and it will expand as you wish.

`anytagName` becomes `<anytagName styleName=''></anytagName>`

No emmet is involved, and there is no tab expansion - only select and keychord.  The emmet expansion route is actually more complicated.  I will add that later.

Comment: thanks for your sugesstion. It solve the problem. the only extra step is to select `anyTagName`. use snippets is another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

[open snipptes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Aqaw.jpg)

step1: open your user code spipptes like above. choose javascript.json. Its directory is `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/snippets`.

step2:custom your snippets like this.

`` {
    "div, react-css-module in js": {
        "prefix": "div,",
        "body": [
            "<div styleName='$1'>$2</div>",
        ],
        "description": ""
    },
    "p, react-css-module in js": {
        "prefix": "p,",
        "body": [
            "<p styleName='$1'>$2</p>",
        ],
        "description": ""
    },
    "span, react-css-module in js": {
        "prefix": "span,",
        "body": [
            "<span styleName='$1'>$2</span>",
        ],
        "description": ""
    },
    "img, react-css-module in js": {
        "prefix": "img,",
        "body": [
            "<img styleName='$1' alt= '$2'",
            "  src={$3}",
            "  srcSet={`",
            "    ${$4} 2x",
            "    ${$5} 3x",
            "  `} ",
            "/>",
        ],
        "description": ""
    },
    "image path": {
        "prefix": "imgpath",
        "body": [
            "'/easicare-mobile/static/images/pages/$1';"
        ]
    }
} ``

so input `div,`, choose the suggestion then press enter will expand to `<div styleName='$1'>$2</div>`.